# Passing a custom Wordpress comment form field of type 'file' to Wordpress hook

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I am able to add an input field of type 'file' to the comment form at my Wordpress Genesis website (using the 'comment_form_default_fields' and 'comment_form_defaults' hooks). But when I go to intercept $_FILES using any of the following hooks: 'pre_comment_content', 'preprocess_comment', or 'comment_post', $_FILES is empty. The filename passes through via the $_POST variable, but I need it in $_FILES to actually upload the file. It's as though Wordpress is screening out the 'file' input type on comment forms for security reasons. How does one get Wordpress to make an exception?